# How to change package source for NPM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

We are developing in a secured environment that has no connection to the internet.
For nuget, we have our own package sources, directories on our secured network and we copy the packages we need into it (after screening).

For npm we want something similar. How do I configure where npm gets its packages?

Comment: check this out https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/npm+Registry . seems you can change what you point your npm to with `npm config set registry`

Comment: You mean a custom [*registry*](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry)?

Answer (score 3):

you should set the registry using: `npm config set registry`

[see npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user)

Comment: thank you (and also  Joey Gough and jonrsharpe). Dont know really why someone downvoted my question without letting know what is so bad about it :(